# how can i use contains inside function?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

```
  void login() async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const StudentPage()),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Tüm alanları doldurunuz.",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to redirect the users I created with Firebase auth to different pages according to their mail type.

For example, if the user is registered with @gmail.com in auth, I want to redirect to one page, if registered with @hotmail.com, to another page. How can I use contains for this? Or is there another method for this?

```
   SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 144, 56)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      login();
                    },
                    child: Text('Giriş Yap', 
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
```

I am using the login function here

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 opportunities to get user's email, you can get it from `emailController.text` or `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(..)` as it will return `Future<UserCredential>`,  you can took advantage from one of them, here is my example code (adept from yours) with `signInWithEmailAndPassword(..)`

```
void login() async {
    try {
      var userCreds = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
      
      if(userCreds.user != null){
        var user = userCreds.user!;
        if(user.email?.contains("@gmail") ?? false){
          ///Your function for gmail
        }else if(user.email?.contains("@hotmail") ?? false){
          ///Your function for hotmail
        }else {
          ///Add more logic as you need
        }
      }

      // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const StudentPage()));
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Tüm alanları doldurunuz.",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
```